# Plotting in Linux without installation on closed systems

Tags: html, linux, plot, gnuplot

I want to plot some basic graphs in Linux. But, I am working in a closed system. The system managers don't let us to install any third party plotting tools like gnuplot etc. because of the security issues.

So, how can i generate simple bar or dot graphs? I don't need advanced graphs. I just want to run a query and get the (x,y) values with sqlplus, save them to a text file and draw a simple trend graph or percentage graph. And then I want to send them to our mail group wia sendmail as a HTML based email.

The system we use is RedHat. Is there any built-in tools? Or can i use any script without installation?

I tried [this](http://www.tutorialspark.com/html5/HTML5_Canvas_dataplot_Demo.php) but Outlook doesn't run javascript :(

Comment: This sounds like a typical [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Rather than trying to find solutions to the stated extremely difficult situation, it would be easily resolved by informing your organisation of your requirement for gnuplot or other secure plotting software. You could also use one of the portable versions of gnuplot(does not require installation) in a secure administrator approved device.

Comment: RHEL 6 example : Unpack `gnuplot-bin-5.0.6-1.el6.tar.gz` to /home/[name]/. ... `cd usr/bin/ && ./gnuplot`. ... Link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/pjg4cr2ghvdlnad/gnuplot-bin-5.0.6-1.el6.tar.gz?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

There are gnuplot packages from RedHat for both RHEL and Fedora. The one for RHEL is horribly out of date (version 4.something) but if you only want to make simple plots it should be fine. Or your sysadmin might be OK with installing the CentOS gnuplot package, which is newer and should be RHEL compatible.

Comment: RHEL 7 example : Unpack `gnuplot-bin-5.0.6-1.el7.tar.gz` to /home/[name]/. ... `cd usr/bin/ && ./gnuplot`. ... Link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/flv5fio106xygxe/gnuplot-bin-5.0.6-1.el7.tar.gz?dl=0

Comment: yes, this worked but I can not save it to a jpeg or png image. just could save it to a svg file but couldn't use it as an image in an email in Outlook.